# Persisting data in infinispan cache to file

Tags: java, file, caching, persistence, infinispan

I'm trying to persist cached data from infinispan 6.0.2 to a file, I'm using the embedded mode and this is the cache configuration:

```
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.eviction().strategy(EvictionStrategy.LRU).maxEntries(1)
      .persistence()
      .passivation(false) // save evicted entries to cache store
      .addSingleFileStore()
         .preload(true)
         .shared(false)
         .fetchPersistentState(true)
         .ignoreModifications(false)
         .purgeOnStartup(false)
         .location(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")+"infinispan")
         //.async().enabled(true).threadPoolSize(5)
         .singleton()
            .enabled(true)
            .pushStateWhenCoordinator(true)
            .pushStateTimeout(20000);
Configuration configuration = builder.build();
```

It does not work for me (and I don't have errors), the file store is created in the file system but contains only "FCS1" and if it's already created nothing happen (i.e. no update).
Here is the code (nothing fancy) for adding key/value pairs to the cache:

```
// Avoid JMX problems related to org.infinispan already registered domain
GlobalConfiguration globalConf = new GlobalConfigurationBuilder()
                                        //.clusteredDefault()
                                        .globalJmxStatistics()
                                        .mBeanServerLookup(DummyMBeanServer.lookup)
                                        .build();
EmbeddedCacheManager manager1 = new DefaultCacheManager(globalConf, configuration);
manager1.start();
Cache<String, String> cache1 = manager1.getCache(); // default cache
cache1.put("key11", "val11");
cache1.put("key12", "val12");
cache1.put("key13", "val13");
cache1.evict("key11"); // a desperate attempt to move this key to the store
cache1.stop();
// when I restart the cache all data is lost
cache1.start();
```

Comment: Pls. provide the complete code. How was the data written?

Comment: Indeed, we need to see the code you call and the assertions you have in place, as suggested by cruftex. Btw, remove the singleton part since it's not relevant for a local cache like this.

Comment: Since passivation is disabled, each put will result in a write to the persistent store, which is a file store, so the evict call is not necessary. How are you verifying that data is lost when cache is started? Have you tried making get calls for the keys you stored? I can't see anything wrong, so the easiest is to take a debugger and follow the interceptor stack to `CacheWriterInterceptor.visitPutKeyValueCommand()`. Alternatively, enable TRACE logging on org.infinispan package and have a look.

Comment: I intentionally disabled passivation to see if something is really saved to the store, then I tried the manual eviction, but nothing happens. I use `cache1.get("key11")` to read entries!

Comment: I've also tried with TRACE mode I could not see anything important then `Preloaded 0 keys in 0 milliseconds` from the `PersistenceManagerImpl`. I will try with the visitor you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the following XML configuration (which is almost the same as the above!) I can find my entries in the store:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:6.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-6.0.xsd"
  >

<!-- Using the cluster mode with grouping API-->

<global>
    <globalJmxStatistics enabled="false" />
</global>

<default>
    <!-- Enbaling eviction/expiration -->
    <eviction strategy="LRU" maxEntries="2000" />
    <expiration lifespan="1000" maxIdle="500" />
    <jmxStatistics enabled="false" />

    <clustering>
        <hash>
            <groups enabled="true" />
        </hash>
    </clustering>       
</default>

<namedCache name="CacheStore">
    <persistence passivation="false">
        <singleFile fetchPersistentState="true"
            ignoreModifications="false"
            purgeOnStartup="false" location="${java.io.tmpdir}">
            <async
                enabled="true"
                flushLockTimeout="15000"
                threadPoolSize="5" />
        </singleFile>
    </persistence>
</namedCache>

</infinispan>
```